# Collapsable List - Display all title using multiline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am having trouble modifying the following code to make it display correctly on mobile, I copied it from W3 Schools collapsable lists tutorial and modified it correctly for desktop.

However on mobile half the writing gets cut off by an ellipsis.

**Desktop**

[image: Desktop Image]

**Mobile**

[image: Mobile Image]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.
Ideally I would like to make the title section span across multiple lines.

See below code for more information.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Do I need to buy now?</h4>
No. Sign up for a free 30-day trial now. With NO obligations.
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Is the free trial fully functional?</h4>
Yes. The free trial comes with all of S2L features. You can give it a test run before you buy.
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Do I need a credit card to sign up for the trial?</h4>
No. We do not collect payment information until you are ready to buy.
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Do you provide a discount for yearly plans?</h4>
     Yes. You save 10% if you choose to pay yearly.
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>How do I activate my trial to a paid version?</h4>
Once you have entered your payment information, you will receive an activation code by mail. <br>
Enter the code into the application and you are ready to go.
    </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the link to the W3 schools tutorial mentioned above:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_lists_collapsible

Comment: Not sure what the issue is.  I don't see any text cut off in the screenshot in the link.

Comment: @db_brad, his images links are squished together, so you probably only clicked on the desktop one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well right now it is using an ellipsis with `white-space: nowrap;` on the overflow rather than breaking to a new line. Give your text a `white-space: normal;`.

**CSS:**

```
#pageone > div a {
  white-space: normal;  
}
```

```css
#pageone > div a {
  white-space: normal;  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page" id="pageone">

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>This title is super long and will overflow to a new line instead of using an ellipsis.</h4>
    No. Sign up for a free 30-day trial now. With NO obligations.
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>This title is super long and will overflow to a new line instead of using an ellipsis.</h4>
    Yes. The free trial comes with all of S2L features. You can give it a test run before you buy.
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>This title is super long and will overflow to a new line instead of using an ellipsis.</h4>
    No. We do not collect payment information until you are ready to buy.
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>This title is super long and will overflow to a new line instead of using an ellipsis.</h4>
         Yes. You save 10% if you choose to pay yearly.
        </div>

        <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h4>This title is super long and will overflow to a new line instead of using an ellipsis.</h4>
    Once you have entered your payment information, you will receive an activation code by mail. <br>
    Enter the code into the application and you are ready to go.
        </div>

      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the education Hunter you are a legend!

Comment: Haha! No problem bud :)